# argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime', but i have a string (Pandas + Matplotlib)

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe

```
published            | sentiment
2022-01-31 10:00:00  | 0
2021-12-29 00:30:00  | 5
2021-12-20           | -5
```

Since some rows don't have hours, minutes and seconds I delete them:

```
df_dominant_topic2['published']=df_dominant_topic2['published'].astype(str).str.slice(0, 10)
df_dominant_topic2['published']=df_dominant_topic2['published'].str.slice(0, 10)
```

I get:

```
published   | sentiment
2022-01-31  | 0
2021-12-29  | 5
2021-12-20  | -5
```

If I plot the data:

```
plt.pyplot.plot_date(df['published'],df['sentiment'] )
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

But I don't know why since it should be a string.
How can I plot it (possibly keeping the temporal order)? Thank you

Comment: Try adding `df_dominant_topic2['published']=pd.to_datetime(df_dominant_topic2['published'])` before you plot but after you trim the hours

Comment: same error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

values=[('2022-01-31 10:00:00',0),('2021-12-29 00:30:00',5),('2021-12-20',-5)]
cols=['published','sentiment']

df_dominant_topic2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns=cols)
df_dominant_topic2['published']=df_dominant_topic2['published'].astype(str).str.slice(0, 10)
df_dominant_topic2['published']=df_dominant_topic2['published'].str.slice(0, 10)
#you may sort the data by date
df_dominant_topic2.sort_values(by='published', ascending=True, inplace=True)
plt.plot(df_dominant_topic2['published'],df_dominant_topic2['sentiment'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: same error :( sorry